# Map to Salesforce Campaigns field missing in S4S connector for sitecore

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

For some reason the "Map to Saleforce Campaigns" field is missing from my S4S Mapping screen.

Here's a screenshot of what it's supposed to look like from the S4S guide:
[image: S4S Web Forms For Marketers Guide]

Am I missing an install component? Is there a setting they needs to be toggled on somewhere? I have a few "Active" campaigns in Salesforce so that's not the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 issues.

1. You need the latest version of S4S connector module.
2. You need to either select a contact or a lead.

Thanks to Terry from FuseIT for getting back to me on ANZAC day!